# Cannot find protocol declaration in objective c

Tags: objective-c, protocols, declaration

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface dog:NSObject<logging>{
@private
int age;
}
@property int age;

@end
@implementation dog
@synthesize age;
-(void)log{
NSLog(@" this is a god having age %d ",age);
}
@end
@protocol logging
-(void)log;
@end
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
dog *loop=[[dog alloc] init];
//[dog setAge:6];
[dog log];
[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

when i try to run this code
This program gives the error "cannot find protocol declaration for logging
Why?

Comment: One thing I cannot find is indentation.

Comment: what does indentation has to do in objective c, else making code easy to read, its a small code you can read, sir?

Comment: @userXXX No, it's **extremely hard to read** due to the lack of indentation (and whitespace in general...). Always indent your code properly. Even if it's just 3 lines. Youknowyoucanreadtextthatlookslikethis,butit'sextremelydifficultsincethere'snoseparationbetweenwords. The very same thing applies to code.

Comment: thnx a lot sir for the kind comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your protocol in `.h` file like this below in-spite of declaring in `.m` file:-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@protocol logging
-(void)log;
@end
@interface dog:NSObject<logging>{
@private
int age;
}
@property int age;

@end
```